# How to read trace files in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I have a mobility trace file produced by SUMO. It has been converted to OMNET++ format by some python script in SUMO package. The output is an .xml file that the SUMO designers say it is in OMNET++ format.

How can I input this trace file in my OMNET++ simulator and use it. The format of one location of one node in a specific time is as follows:

[image]

I know how to use it in my simulator but I am not sure how I can import this trace into OMNET++. It is possible to write a code in Matlab and extract important data like time, position, etc and get rid of tags but I want OMNET++ to use the tags and extract required information itself in some module.

Is there any module in OMNET++ to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this file format is used by the [opponet](https://code.google.com/p/opponet/) module library, an old library used for simulating opportunistic networks. It is not for *The INET Framework* or *Veins*, as could be hoped.

Note, however, that Veins can directly connect to SUMO. It is also designed for simulating wireless networks of cars. For more information, please refer to its homepage at http://veins.car2x.org/